# What do "...or will I?" constructions mean?

Tags: grammar

I've seen this construction, but I can't understand its meaning:

> "I will do something, or will I?"

I can't understand why there's a question after an affirmative sentence with the same meaning.

This question is difficult to research.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Interpretation requests are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: This isn't a documented expression that I can find, but generally it's used in a humorous tone of voice to suggest that the speaker is allowing the possibility that his previous statement is a lie, hence it's aim is to deceive the listener by giving the speaker an air of untrustworthiness

Comment: @MετάEd ~ I've seen a few times now where you keep commenting that questions are out of scope, but not every question is capable of being researched. You need to take each question on an individual basis, and not just comment willy-nilly

Comment: @Bobby''V0ight''Peru-------- Every question is capable of being researched. If you want to discuss this, I'm in [chat]. Cheers

Comment: @MετάEd ~ technically that may be the case, but some research is so obscure that it is unreasonable to expect it of people. If you think that this question is possible to be researchd then please show me how one would go about researching this type of question. I'd love to learn such a method myself. Anyway, this'll be my last post on the matter

Comment: Sorry for that, but I can't imagine how to do a search in this case, and I will thank you if you show me how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructions like

> I'm going to take out the garbage... or will I?

are largely comedic structures. By immediately asking "or will I?" the affirmation is humorously undermined. Usually, the "or will I" part is emphasized.

If there are multiple people in the conversation, you might utter the "or will I?" part in a low voice, so that only a particular person can hear you. This would indicate to that person that you aren't actually sure you are going to perform the action, or that you are, in fact, not going to perform it.

In this kind of use, the "or will I?" part can be thought of as a kind of *aside*, similar to Shakespearean [asides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aside) addressed directly to the audience. In this example, it would be an aside to a particular participant in the conversation.

That said, you can also use the construction in a two-person conversation, where the "or will I?" part is addressed to a kind of invisible audience.

This construction is similar to the following construction you sometimes see at the end of movies, TV shows, and comic books:

> [The end... or is it?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheEndOrIsIt)